# Convert cmd ffmpeg script to shell

Tags: shell, cmd, ffmpeg, nas

its very simple code for cmd but i cant get how its should work on my nas with shell

Please help to convert script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
```

Settings

```
set sWorkFolder=d:\workfolder
set sSourceFolder=%sWorkFolder%\waiting-to-convert
set sDestFolder=%sWorkFolder%\done
set sBackupFolder=%sWorkFolder%\trash
set sPath2ffmpeg=%sWorkFolder%\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe
```

Start cycle

```
for /r "%sSourceFolder%" %%i in (*.mp4) do call :action "%%i"

endlocal
exit /b

:action
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "sSourcePath=%~dp1"
set "sDestPath=%sDestFolder%!sSourcePath:%sSourceFolder%=!"
if not exist "%sDestPath%." md "%sDestPath%"
set "sDestFile=%sDestPath%%~n1.720p%~x1"

"%sPath2ffmpeg%" -i "%~f1" -vcodec h264 -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:min(720p\,ih)" -b:v 2000k -preset faster -acodec copy -y "%sDestFile%"

set "sBackupPath=%sBackupFolder%!sSourcePath:%sSourceFolder%=!"
if not exist "%sBackupPath%." md "%sBackupPath%"

move /y "%~1" "%sBackupPath%"

endlocal
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

Shell scripts are normally `echo off`. You can get debugging output with `set -vx` and turn that off with `set +vx`. These two can be placed anywhere in the file (preferably on a line separate from others). (And as you will notice below `set` is very different in shell that cmd).

The first line of your script should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

After you save your file, you need to execute the unix/linux command

```
chmod 755 myScript.sh
```

To mark it executable.

If you created file on windows, or use windows ftp, or windows anything, once you have file to *nix, do

```
dos2unix myScript.sh
```

---

`set var=value` is accomplished with `DestPath=/path/to/dir`. use

```
if [ ! -d "$DestPath" ] ; then mkdir "$DestPath'; fi
```

All vars are referenced like `"$var"`.

`move` is shortened to `mv`. Consult `man mv` for find equivalent  opt of `/y`.

```
for file in *.mp4 ; do cmd "$file" ; done
```

I don't understand your `do :action` in the for loop, so I have substituted `cmd` to indicate 'do some work'. You can call external commands (multiple), have an defined function that you call OR have a multi-cmd pipeline, like

```
cmd1 file | filter_cmd | filter2_cmd > outfile
```

Because you have labels in your code (i.e. `:action`), you should be aware that only `csh` allows for `goto` like branching (you don't want to start coding in `csh`!). You'll have to refactor your code to work only inside `for` and `while` loops, relying on `break` and `continue` to change processing inside the loops.

Convert this much, then use http://shellcheck.net for errors. Post a new question with your corrected code, and show exact error messages.

IHTH

Comment: `do` is part of the `for`-Syntax. `call` calls another part of the script (starting with a Label `:action`, ending with `exit /b` (here)) with `"%%i` (one of the .mp4 files) as a Parameter. This Parameter is referenced in the "subroutine" with `%1` or a [modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of it.

Comment: @Stephan : thanks for explaining that bit of `cmd` syntax. (Do they still call them .bat files? ).

Comment: we call the scripts "batchfile" and name them `.bat` or `.cmd`. There isn't really a common name for the "language" because it isn't a real language - just a bunch of commands and executables (we speak of scripts, not programs). Some call it "batch", some call it "cmd" and there are probably some more names for it.

Comment: I cant get how to make this on sh:
`set "sSourcePath=%~dp1"
 set "sDestPath=%sDestFolder%!sSourcePath:%sSourceFolder%=!"`
in cycle I get Destination of source file like:
`"sSourcePath=d:\workfolder\waiting-to-convert\videofolder1\video1.mp4"`
then:
`"sDestPath=%sDestFolder%`
is:`sDestPath=d:\workfolder\done\`
and `!sSourcePath:%sSourceFolder%=!`
is: `\videofolder1\video1.mp4`
together: `set "sDestPath=%sDestFolder%!``sSourcePath:%sSourceFolder%=!"`
is: `d:\workfolder\done\videofolder1\video1.mp4`

its very importan to keep all old path in Done and trash folder

Comment: stop using `%var%`. and use `"$var"` for starters. Then "Convert this much, then use http://shellcheck.net for errors. Post a new question with your corrected code, and show exact error messages." Good luck.